# How can we validate individual form field In Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, validation, form-validation, custom-field

In Magento 1.x we can validate individual form field like.

```
<input class="input-text required-entry" id="name" title="First Name" type="text" name="name" value="" onblur="validate(this)"/>

function validate(id){
   Validation.validate(id);
}
```

**In Magento 2.x How can we validate individual form field?**

I want to validate only one field from multiple fields in a single form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can validate specific field using below code of line.

```
<script>
require([
  'jquery',
  'mage/mage',
], function($){
   $( "#new-button" ).click(function() {        
       $('input[name="field_mobile"]').validation();
       if(!$('input[name="field_mobile"]').validation('isValid')){
           return false;
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

**NOTE:** make sure you have added `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}` in **form** tag.

Comment: To make it work you will need to wrap the field with in a form: like it is shown in the other answer by Ankit Shah

Comment: yes, that's I have added in 'NOTE'.

Comment: Thanks chirag, but in the question it is not form tag at all so is not completely clear specially when the other answer doesn't have any points.

Answer (score 9):

I found this one to work:

```
$.validator.validateSingleElement('#input-id');
```

More about how it's implemented and used here: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5504

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form"
      action="<?php Your Action ?>"
      id="form"
      name="form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
      enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Title') ?>" class="input-text data-validate="{required:true}"  value=""  />
</form>
```

Comment: I want to validate only one field from multiple fields in a single form. this will work?

Comment: Please try & let me know if any query

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Please post ur whole page code with file path in question

Comment: I have created a new button in the registration page and when on clicking i want to validate the first name.

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/12/magento2-form-validation/

Comment: this is form validation i need only one field validation from multiple.